# lightning:RadioGroup inside aura:iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, radiogroup

I'm attempting to generate a lightning:radioGroup selection inside my data table, I have a object returning a `List<String>` but it isn't giving me the styling, it's spitting out the data correct.

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.column.selectOptionRow}" var="option" indexVar="idx"> 
    <lightning:radioGroup aura:id="radioGrp- + idx" name="radioButtonGroup" label="{!option.radioLabel}" options="{!option.radioValue}" value="{!v.radioGrpValue}" onchange="{! c.handleRadioGroupChange}"/>
</aura:iteration>
```

And it appears like this

[image]

Am I going about this wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[lightning:radioGroup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_radioGroup.htm) is a self-contained element that expects an attribute named "options" to be set. What you're doing is basically showing a bunch of "empty" radio groups.

If you want to use an iteration, specify `lightning:input type="radio" name="radioGroup"`. Each radio group item must have the same name. Note that aura:id cannot be dynamically rendered, so don't bother trying.

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.column.selectOptionRow}" var="option" indexVar="idx"> 
    <lightning:input aura:id="assignmentOptions" name="radioButtonGroup" label="{!option.radioLabel}" type="radio" options="{!option.radioValue}" value="{!v.radioGrpValue}" onchange="{! c.handleRadioGroupChange}"/>
</aura:iteration>
```

If you want to use lightning:radioGroup, then simply specify the options in an attribute:

```
<lightning:radioGroup aura:id="assignmentOptions" name="radioButtonGroup" options="{!v.column.selectOptionRow}" value="{!v.radioGrpValue}" onchange="{! c.handleRadioGroupChange}"/>
```

*(Note: I haven't carefully checked all the attributes, some additional tweaking may be needed. Please check the documentation.)*

Comment: Thanks, there is also some binding that I wasn't aware was so strict.. my properties had to be named `label` and `value`, I swore I tried your resolution before I must of been burned out end of day..

Comment: Also to add to this, I didn't realize it took a `type` which is `button` as an attribute